# GlassPane behaves weird

Tags: java, swing, glasspane

I created a `JPanel` inside it i put a `JCheckBox` and two buttons:

[image]

when checkbox is checked a glassPane with transparent color (alpha = 100) is showed above the panel and contains a label displaying the `String` "Loading...", the problem is that the location of checkbox changes when glassPane is displayed:

[image]

and when i change the size of the frame the glassPane become opaque and all component which were visible under glasspane become invisible.

[image]

and when i change the size to smaller size, the background of the glassPane changes and get darker and the label string "Loading" become blurred

[image]

Here is my code which is inspired by Oracle tutorial about GlassPane [GlassPane Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

```
package com.training.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class Training extends JFrame
{
    JCheckBox changeGlass;
    JButton button1, button2;

    public Training()
    {
        setBounds(100, 100, 400, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Test Glass Pane");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        JPanel glass = (JPanel) getGlassPane();
        glass.setOpaque(true);
        glass.setBackground(new Color(120, 120, 120, 100));
        glass.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        glass.add(new JLabel("Loading ..."));

        changeGlass = new JCheckBox("Show Glass Pane", false);

        changeGlass.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
        {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
            {
                glass.setVisible(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
            }
        });

        button1 = new JButton("Select");
        button2 = new JButton("Change");

        getContentPane().add(changeGlass);
        getContentPane().add(button1);
        getContentPane().add(button2);

        glass.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
        {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                redispatchEvent(e, (JPanel) getContentPane(), glass);
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                redispatchEvent(e, (JPanel) getContentPane(), glass);
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
            {
                redispatchEvent(e, (JPanel) getContentPane(), glass);
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
            {
                redispatchEvent(e, (JPanel) getContentPane(), glass);
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                redispatchEvent(e, (JPanel) getContentPane(), glass);
            }
        });
    }

    public void redispatchEvent(MouseEvent e, JPanel panel, JPanel glass)
    {
        Point panelPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(glass, e.getPoint(), panel);
        Component c = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(panel, (int) panelPoint.getX(), (int) panelPoint.getY());

        Point componentPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(panel, panelPoint, c);

        if (c != null && c.equals(changeGlass))
        {
            c.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(c, e.getID(), e.getWhen(), e.getModifiers(), (int) componentPoint.getX(), (int) componentPoint.getY(), e.getClickCount(), e
                    .isPopupTrigger()));
        }
        else
        {
            e.consume();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone correct me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Swing does not do semi-transparent well, I'm afraid. There are tricks to this, but I'll have to look them up.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So transparence with glassPane is not possible like it works with setOpacity of JFrame, i found a solution is to prepare png picture with lower alpha and add the picture to label as imageIcon, but i don't know how to stretch the picture to take all glassPane space.

Comment: I believe that it's possible, but it takes some tricks (where are @camickr or MadProgrammer when you need them?). Perhaps it would be better to use a JLayer. I'm checking that out right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for the probable reason for the problem and a couple of solutions. Basically because you are using a transparent background you need to make sure you paint the background of the glass pane yourself.

So I would create a custom panel to use as your glass pane so you can manage the painting of the background. Then you set this panel as the glass pane of the frame.

Comment: 1+, please see my comment to the original question -- you answered my prayer!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for your prayers to help newbie people like me.